# Android Stack Overflow (getIntrinsicHeight)

Tags: android, drawable, stack-overflow

Has anyone come across this problem? The app changes image every few mins, after several hours the app crashes because of a stack overflow. The problem is in an internal Android call getIntrinsicHeight which is called from setImageDrawable.

Here is the sample call stack.

```
android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(LayerDrawable.java:561) at
android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(LayerDrawable.java:561) at
android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(LayerDrawable.java:561) at
android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(LayerDrawable.java:561) at
android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(LayerDrawable.java:561) at
android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(LayerDrawable.java:561) at
android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(LayerDrawable.java:561) at
com.hdms.manager.Drawable.NightlifeImageView.setImageDrawable(NightlifeImageView.java:34)
    at com.hdms.manager.Drawable.TitleBar$20.run(TitleBar.java:1134)
    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4713)
    at com.hdms.manager.Drawable.TitleBar.onLoadDone(TitleBar.java:1119)
    at com.hdms.manager.Drawable.TitleBar.onImmediateFind(TitleBar.java:1150)
    at
com.hdms.manager.Fragments.WebImageLoader.getImage(WebImageLoader.java:110)
    at com.hdms.manager.Drawable.TitleBar.updatePlayState(TitleBar.java:923)
    at com.hdms.manager.MainActivity.onUpdatePlayState(MainActivity.java:1870)
    at com.hdms.manager.HDMSLiveAPI.onUpdateZone(HDMSLiveAPI.java:328)
    at com.hdms.manager.HDMSLiveAPI.evalMsg(HDMSLiveAPI.java:131)
    at com.hdms.manager.MainActivity.onMessage(MainActivity.java:1601)
    at com.hdms.manager.WebSocketClass$1$1$2.run(WebSocketClass.java:211)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the image changing code.

```
mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // Transition drawable with a transparent drawable and the final bitmap
        TransitionDrawable td = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[]
        {
            aImageView.getDrawable() != null ? aImageView.getDrawable() : new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT),
            aResult
        });

        td.setCrossFadeEnabled(true);

        ImageView.ScaleType scaleType = aImageView.getScaleType();
        aImageView.setImageDrawable(td);
        aImageView.setScaleType(scaleType);
        td.startTransition(mFadeInTime);
    }
});
```

Comment: Huh. That is weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like only some devices have this problem; I have no idea why it happens, but here is my work around.

```
try
{
    // Transition drawable with a transparent drawable and the final bitmap
    TransitionDrawable td = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[]
            {
                    aImageView.getDrawable(),
                    aResult
            });

    td.setCrossFadeEnabled(true);
    td.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, aImageView.getWidth(), aImageView.getHeight()));

    ImageView.ScaleType scaleType = aImageView.getScaleType();
    aImageView.setImageDrawable(td);
    aImageView.setScaleType(scaleType);
    td.startTransition(mFadeInTime);
}
catch (StackOverflowError e)
{}
```

There have been no bad side effects from ignoring this error.